# Making Awesome guess file endings from application name

Tags: autocomplete, awesome-wm

In bash-completion when I *tab* to complete a filename and the application has a preferred file extension, bash will intelligently guess it.

As an example

```
evince test/te --*tab*--> evince test/test.pdf
```

even if there were files like test.tex, test.jpg etc. in that folder.

Is there a way to make the awesome prompt guess the file extension in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `rc.lua` you could hack the the call `awful.prompt` and specify the additional parameter `completion_callback`. See the lua doc for [`awful.prompt`](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/awful.prompt.html) and [`awful.completion`](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/awful.completion.html). I made a quick search and found a [forum post providing an example of a `awful.completion.bash`](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=405002#p405002).

Answer (score 1):

In my rc.lua I define a couple helper functions

```
local function shellcomp(command,cur_pos,ncomp)
   return awful.completion.shell(command,cur_pos,ncomp,"bash")
end

local function run_promptbox()
   awful.prompt.run{
   prompt = 'Run: ',
   text = '',
   textbox= awful.screen.focused().mypromptbox.widget,
   completion_callback=shellcomp
   }
end
```

Then put the following to `globalkeys` (replace any previous binding on modkey+r).

```
awful.key({ modkey },  "r", run_promptbox,  {description = "run prompt", group = "launcher"}),
```